# AWS outgoing requests ELB for EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I would like to know if it would be possible to create a load balancer for outgoing requests on AWS-EC2.

```
Example (1 EC2, 2 IPs):
1 # Request send with ip -> 2.4.8.15  
2 # Request send with ip -> 16.23.4.2  
3 # Request send with ip -> 2.4.8.15  
...
```

Thanks for help

EDIT --

I'm using an API with IP rate limit  (500 per minute) and i want to increase this limitation to 2000 per minute. With a constraint keep a low latency.

Comment: What do you mean by outgoing load balancer?

Comment: https://xyproblem.info - are you trying to have a different external IP everytime?

Comment: If you need a fixed egress IP, then you should put your instances into a private subnet and use a NAT Gateway https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary to be able to dispatch requests fairly

Comment: What does 'fairly' mean in this context? Fair to whom? Fair in what way?

Comment: For me two ways:  
- first after x requests switch on other IP   
- switch on other IP after each request (cicular)

Comment: But why? Why do you want/need to do this at all?

Comment: @jarmod updated in my post.

Comment: I recommend that you work with the API owner to understand options, paid or otherwise, for increasing your request rate.